# SQL Server: Restoring DB via linked server - Database intermittently stuck in restoring state (even with RECOVERY option)

Tags: sql-server, database, restore, alter, recovery

I am doing restores across servers via dynamic sql and linked servers as follows:

```
Exec ('USE MASTER; RESTORE DATABASE <dbname> FROM DISK = <path> WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY') AT <target server>
```

The database is set to single user mode before the above statement runs. However, on intermittent occasions, when trying to get the database back to multi user mode I get the a query timeout from the the target server and error:

> ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state

I have looked around for this error but apparently I'm should not be getting it when using the RECOVERY option.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out today. The culprit behind the issue was the default remote query time out for Sql Server which is 600s (10mins). More on this in the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040(v=sql.105).aspx

My restore usually takes around 10mins to complete, sometimes a bit less so it succeeds and sometimes a bit more when it fails. Hence the issue was manifesting itself intermittently.

I increased the remote query time out on the source server to 36000s and it restored successfully. Just to prove the point, I  decreased the remote query time out to a small figure like 60s and got the same symptom again.

Michelle - I set the database in single user to kill any running queries before the restore and to make sure there are no conflicts whilst the database is restored. This would eliminate the Exclusive Access could not be obtained because the database is in use error. Alternatively the database can be put to offline before the restore is initiated and back to online afterwards.